# Xelement extract xml from different files and combine back to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I have this XML.  I want to find the first/extract first one by order-no="00070853"
in C# and combine later with same xml from other files so it's
same schema.  I've tried (just for extract but knowing how to combine would be nice too)

```
      IEnumerable<XElement> orderXml = from el in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "order")
      where (string)el.Attribute(ns + "order-no").Value == badOrder
      select el;
```

Below is  example xml (it has schema I want too)

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <orders xmlns="http://www.bla.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31">
<order order-no="00070853">
    <order-date>2015-12-10T21:58:26.000Z</order-date>
    <created-by>storefront</created-by>        
    <taxation>net</taxation>
    <invoice-no>55023028</invoice-no>
    <customer>
        <customer-no>10028489</customer-no>            
    </customer>
    <status>
        <order-status>NEW</order-status>
        <shipping-status>NOT_SHIPPED</shipping-status>
        <confirmation-status>CONFIRMED</confirmation-status>
        <payment-status>NOT_PAID</payment-status>
    </status>        
</order>

<order order-no="10020785">
    <order-date>2015-12-10T21:58:04.000Z</order-date>
    <created-by>storefront</created-by>
    <taxation>net</taxation>
    <invoice-no>12022832</invoice-no>
    <customer>
        <customer-no>10027992</customer-no>
    </customer>
    <status>
        <order-status>NEW</order-status>
        <shipping-status>NOT_SHIPPED</shipping-status>
        <confirmation-status>CONFIRMED</confirmation-status>
        <payment-status>NOT_PAID</payment-status>
    </status>
</order>
     </orders>
```

Comment: You queastion is _not clear_. You wanna add the filtered node to another XML?

Comment: @DenisL What's the problem with your code?

Comment: I'm going through hundreds of files containing XML in the format above.   (simplified).  Some of the orders have failed so  I want to extract those<order> node(plus everything below) from different xml files and combine them into 1 XML file using the same schema.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every file you process has the same exact structure, you could just read in the files and throw the elements into a new document.  You might want to keep track of the file you obtained that data from.

```
var orderNo = "00070853";
var dir = @"c:\path\to\files\";
XNamespace ns = "http://www.bla.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31";
XNamespace meta = "urn:file.combiner:meta";
var newDoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(ns + "orders",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "meta", meta),
        from p in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, @"*.xml")
        from e in XDocument.Load(p).Descendants(ns + "order")
        where (string)e.Attribute("order-no") == orderNo
        select new XElement(e.Name,
            new XAttribute(meta + "path", p), // lets add the original path as an attribute
            e.Nodes()
        )
    )
);
```